# Stack overflow with recursive function

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I'm trying to make a recursive function where i pass in a integer and a list. I want to append a certain number of "-" (dashes) to the list if the length of the list is less than the integer as follows:

```
let rec dashes (longest, l1) =  
    if length l1 = longest then l1 
    else ["-"]@l1@dashes(longest,l1);;
```

However I get a stack overflow and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You're calling the function recursively with the exact same arguments, causing an infinite loop. And since it's not tail recursive it will cause a stack overflow, rather than just go on looping forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive call to `dashes` passes through the original `l1` argument, so the list length never grows, and the terminating condition remains false.